# CMake - Install Find script for depencency together with script

Tags: c++, cmake, find-package

I am making a CMake library around some installable SDK. So the dependency tree looks like:

```
Application   -->   MyLibrary   -->   OfficialSDK
```

This SDK is installed by some `setup.exe` and does not have a CMake module.
So instead I include a custom find script inside *MyLibrary*: `MyLibrary/cmake/FindOfficialSDK.cmake`. Then inside the `CMakeLists.txt` of *MyLibrary* I can use `find_package(OfficialSDK)`.

This works well for *MyLibrary*. I can build it and install it, together with the CMake export. So then *Application* can run `find_package(MyLibrary)` out of the box, since *MyLibrary* was installed properly using CMake.

However, when configuring *Application* I get an error:

> Target "Application" links to target "OfficialSDK" but the target was not found.

Okay, so *MyLibrary* remembers it needs *OfficialSDK*, but it cannot find it in this CMake project.
I could solve this by including `cmake/FindOfficialSDK.cmake` in *Application*, but I would rather not make my users to copy the find script in case I need to update it in the future.

Is there some way of including the imported target *OfficialSDK* and install it together with *MyLibrary*, so *Application* doesn't need to search for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, largely based on https://discourse.cmake.org/t/install-findpackage-script/5307.

Another example I found inside Pagmo2, for a custom `FindBoost` script: https://github.com/esa/pagmo2/blob/master/pagmo-config.cmake.in#L10

In a nutshell, I've added the following:

- Added an install for my custom find script: `install(FILE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_DIR}/cmake/FindOfficialSDK ...)`
- Added a custom `*-config.cmake.in` script that will be installed, aside from the more automatic `*-targets.cmake` export
- Added an explicit `find_dependency(OfficialSDK)` (not `find_package`) inside this config script, but inside a clause that adds the *MyLibrary* cmake install directory to the CMake module path, so the custom find script is used.

A complete example can be seen this PR: [https://github.com/ET-BE/AdsClient/pull/1/files](https://github.com/ET-BE/AdsClient/pull/1/files#diff-da74ec210e1e23a6158df2c63642b6c95dd51ecc27c759f25fedba5353cf2b41) (as well as a bunch of other stuff). The *OfficialSDK* is TwinCAT's ADS library.

Comment: "Added an explicit `find_package(OfficialSDK)` inside this config script" - In such cases it is better to use [find_dependency](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/CMakeFindDependencyMacro.html#command:find_dependency) macro. Unlike to `find_package`, this macro correctly passes REQUIRED/optional aspects of requesting your package (`MyLibrary`) to the requesting of its dependency (`OfficialSDK`).